# Mongoose. Automatically change value on a given date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I have a simple webapp with ExpressJS and Mongoose.
And my User schema looks something like this:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
     dateexp: Date,
     active: { type: Boolean, default: false}
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

What I wanted to do is make app check all user's "dateexp" with "date.now" and change the value of "active" to true if it passes.

Problem is: I need app to check this value automatically, every day at least.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

No way to do this with Mongoose alone.

My advice (for what it's worth) would be to have something like:

```
last_activity: { type: Date }
```

... that you update every time the user logs in. That way, your database doesn't have to know whether or not a user is "active" – your application can figure that out based on a comparison of `last_activity` and the current date.

It's also easy to query against, so if you have batch jobs or whatever that should only apply to "active" users, you just write a query that finds all users whose `last_activity` date is less than, say, 30 days ago.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. One more question - what if I have collection of "posts" for example, and I have to make something like TTL expiry, that would not delete it, but instead just change it automatically - what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Again – no way to change automatically. You can do a TTL to *delete*, but not to modify. I'd stick with the strategy of just including a timestamp in the document and then letting the application decide whether or not something is "active".